# Make pattern matching into nice code

Tags: wpf, refactoring, resharper

So.. I got this converter in WPF that is supposed to get an Orientation as parameter. If not, the converter should just assign the orientation to Horizontal.

This is my code:

```
 Orientation orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
if (parameter is Orientation)
     orientation = (Orientation) parameter;
```

However, resharper puts a wiggle under "is" and suggests that I "Merge cast with type check". Using refactoring, it looks like this:

```
Orientation orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
if (parameter is Orientation orientation1)
    orientation = orientation1;
```

Which uses a dummy variable.

I think my own creation is the nicest and cleanest, but resharper disagrees. How would you write this piece of code?

I know resparper can be configured, but mostly I like this type of suggestion. It is just when dealing with structs it seems to go bonkers.

Comment: I think this is opinion based. I love Merges

Comment: Of couse it is :-) Most stuff is when it comes to best practice. It even depends on who you think will read your code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my opinion R# complicates code here by using latest c# features. your variant is fine and clear, I don't see a need to change it (it is just 3 lines!)

however consider using `as` operator with fallback to default value (requires nullable type `Orientation?`)

```
object parameter1 = Orientation.Vertical;

Orientation o1 = (parameter1 as Orientation?) ?? Orientation.Horizontal;

object parameter2 = "Vertical";

Orientation o2 = (parameter2 as Orientation?) ?? Orientation.Horizontal;
```

returns

```
Orientation.Vertical
Orientation.Horizontal
```